# Unix Shell Loop through files and replace texts

Tags: shell, loops, unix, sed

I am fairly new to this stuff, and I need a shell file to loop through all ".xml" files in a folder, and do some text replacements.
So far I have come up with this:

```
sed "s/old_text/new_text/g" testfile.xml -i
```

However, I want this to run on all xml files in the current folder, not just on "testfile.xml". Furthermore, how can I make a backup of the original file ?

Any input is more than welcomed!
Thankls a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run `sed` on all the xml files, just specify the wildcard

```
sed "s/old_text/new_text/g" *.xml -i
```

To create a backup, just specify the extension after `-i`:

```
sed "s/old_text/new_text/g" *.xml -i~
```

Note that's usually better to use XML aware tools to handle XML.

Comment: ...and just pray that neither `old_text` nor `new_text` contain any of `$, /, \1, &, ?, *, (, ), [, ], \+, ., etc`. Just be aware that sed does NOT operate on strings, it operates on regexps with a restricted character set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460 and consider using a tool that does operate on strings, e.g. awk. You can reduce the risk of breakage slightly by using single quotes instead of double around the command.

Comment: @EdMorton: True, but awk doesn't parse XML, either :)

Comment: It does if you use the XML library, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawkextlib.html, but mainly I just wanted to give the self-declared newbie a heads up that he will not be using strings with sed.

Comment: @EdMorton: Interesting, I didn't know they exist. Could you provide links?

Comment: just updated my previous comment to include a link. See also http://sourceforge.net/projects/gawkextlib/

Comment: I have about 150 substitutions that I need to make, and yes, they involve ampersants, hashtag, semicolon and some others. I tried via batch file, but I could not find an easy workable solution. I am using sed because this is what I found by googling around, but if you have a safer (easy) idea, I would be delighted to research it. Just point me in a direction :)

Comment: See my first comment for direction. Without sample input/output there's not much more to be said and you've already selected an answer so I doubt if anyone's looking at this any more anyway. It was dumb luck that I happened across this again just now while I was looking for something else.

Answer (score 3):

For all `.xml` files that lie in the current directory:

```
sed -i.bak 's/old_text/new_text/g' *.xml
```

To recurse into subdirectories, combine with `find`:

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i.bak 's/old_text/new_text/g' '{}' \;
```

The backup files will end in `.xml.bak` this way (the parameter to `-i` is appended to the original file name).

Comment: Should point out that this creates .bak versions of all .xml files, rather than just the ones which are updated.

Comment: what if I don't want to have backup files

Answer (score 2):

**a practical shell script, if you intend to sanitize a bunch of files with a number of measures – things that will get a little impractical on a single line...**

```
# only take files form certain subfolders and certain extensions

# be careful to not tamper with .git or .svn folders 
# - thus excluding all hidden folders as an extra precaution
# - also tampering with node_modules is a bad idea

FILES=$(find . -type f -regextype posix-extended     \
    -regex "^\./(public|source)/.*\.(scss|js)$"         \
    -not -regex ".*\/(\.|node_modules).*")

for f in $FILES
do
echo "Processing $f file..."

# all files: prune trailing whitespace on each file.
sed -i 's/ *$//' $f

if [[ $f =~ \.js$ ]]; then
    echo "javascript file!"
    # DO stuff
fi

if [[ $f =~ \.scss$ ]]; then
    echo "scss file!"
    # \b whole word matching – stackoverflow.com/a/1032039/444255
    sed -i 's/\#000\b/black/g' $f
    sed -i 's/\#000000\b/black/g' $f
    sed -i 's/\#fff\b/white/g' $f
    sed -i 's/\#ffffff\b/white/g' $f
fi

done
```

**caveat:** with great power comes great responsibility, and mass-replacement means great power...

Comment: This doesn't work if a file name contains space.